# How does Kubernetes know on which node to schedule its POD when PVs are backed by logical volumes?

Tags: kubernetes

If i implement a CSI driver that will create logical volumes via lvcreate command, and give those volumes for Kubernetes to make PVs from, how will Kubernetes know the volume/node association so that it can schedule a POD which uses this PV on the node where my newly-created logical volume resides? Does it just automagically happen?

Comment: Hi, @J.Doe, did the answer resolve your question?

Comment: Yes, Suresh. Thank you!

Comment: :) glad it was helpful. Could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k8s Scheduler can be influenced using volume topology.

Here is the design proposal which walks through the whole dimension

> Allow topology to be specified for both pre-provisioned and dynamic provisioned PersistentVolumes so that the Kubernetes scheduler can correctly place a Pod using such a volume to an appropriate node.
>   [Volume Topology-aware Scheduling](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-topology-scheduling.md)